# How to make a GreaseMonkey script affect elements in a page before they're displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I'm trying to ensure that images in a certain website are not displayed, but the alt text is still displayed. Initially I attempted to accomplish this with Stylish (using Firefox) and asked the following question:

[How to force an image's alt text to display instead of the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122253/how-to-force-an-images-alt-text-to-display-instead-of-the-image/)

The accepted answer provided me with an alternative solution using Greasemonkey. The script uses [waitForKeyElements](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891) to hide images even if they're added using AJAX.

I changed the given script to the following:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Hide pics except for alt text
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
    * {                                         \
        background-image: none !important;      \
    }                                           \
" );

waitForKeyElements ("img", hideImageExceptForAltText);

function hideImageExceptForAltText (jNode) {
    var imgAlt = jNode.attr("alt");
    var imgTitle = jNode.attr("title");

    jNode.css("display", "none");

    var newSpan = $("<span></span>");
    newSpan.attr("title", imgTitle);
    newSpan.append(imgAlt);

    jNode.parent().append(newSpan);
}
```

Just like the original script, this has the problem that the images are still displayed for a few moments as the page is loading.

Is it possible to ensure that the given function will prevent images on a page from being displayed immediately, so that they won't be visible at all?

EDIT: Brock Adams' reply had the clue I was missing. In case anyone is looking for something like this, the following is what I ended up using. It works fine on the site I needed it for, but I can't guarantee it will work on other sites or other browsers than Firefox.

The following hides images and replaces them with a link (except for background images). Clicking that link will display the image.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        TCRF images
// @namespace   SOMETHING
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle ( "\
    * {\
       background-image: none !important;\
    }\
\
    img.gmImgHideHidden {\
       display: none !important;\
    }\
" );

var num = 0;

function gmImgHideShowImg(imgId, linkId)
{
    // Using plain JavaScript because the page itself may not have jquery
    var img = document.getElementById(imgId);
    img.className = img.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)gmImgHideHidden(?!\S)/g , '' );

    var lnk = document.getElementById(linkId);
    lnk.parentNode.removeChild(lnk);
}

// Exporting the "show image" function so that it can be used in the webpage
unsafeWindow.gmImgHideShowImg = exportFunction(gmImgHideShowImg, unsafeWindow);

waitForKeyElements ("img", hideImageExceptForAltText);

function hideImageExceptForAltText (jNode) {
    var imgId = jNode.attr("id");

    // Ensuring an id exists so the image can be searched for later
    if(typeof(imgId) == "undefined")
    {
        imgId = "gmImgHideImg" + num;
        jNode.attr("id", imgId);
    }

    var imgDisp = jNode.css("display");

    var imgAlt = jNode.attr("alt");
    jNode.addClass("gmImgHideHidden");

    var linkId = "gmImgHideLink" + num;

    var linkNode = $("<a></a>");
    linkNode.attr("id", linkId);
    linkNode.append("Image: " + imgAlt);
    linkNode.attr("onclick", "gmImgHideShowImg('" + imgId + "', '" + linkId + "'); return false;");

    jNode.parent().append(linkNode);

    num++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple, robust way to do this is to set CSS first-thing, before any of the rest of the page loads.

`@run-at document-start` and `GM_addStyle()` do this. (on Firefox; not tested on latest Tampermonkey)

That way, the images are not displayed even for a fraction of a second, like they are with the original code or with a complicated, finicky `MutationObserver` approach.

This complete script shows the process:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Hide pics except for alt text
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @run-at   document-start
// ==/UserScript==
GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
    * {                                         \
        background-image: none !important;      \
    }                                           \
    img {                                       \
        display: none !important;               \
    }                                           \
" );

/*--- $(document).ready() is not always needed for modern Firefox, but
    use for maximum portability, when script runs at document-start.
*/
$(document).ready ( function () {
    waitForKeyElements ("img", hideImageExceptForAltText);
} );

function hideImageExceptForAltText (jNode) {
    var imgAlt      = jNode.attr("alt")     || "";
    var imgTitle    = jNode.attr("title")   || "";

    jNode.after ('<span title="' + imgTitle + '">' + imgAlt + '</span>');
}
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because `@run-at   document-start` was what I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is without a doubt the best solution here. Combined with early injection by `@run-at document-start` we can make the script pretty much bullet-proof. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qL845k9/19/) (tested with Firefox 40) to see it in action.

I think the code is pretty self-explanatory. I've annotated the subtleties, but leave a comment if there's anything you don't understand.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==
"use strict";

/* part one: <img> elements */

(new MutationObserver(function(Records, Obs) {
    for (let R of Records) {/* examine each mutation record: */
        /* if the record specifies an attribute mutation… */
        if (
            R.attributeName === "src" &&
            (R.target instanceof Element) && /* this check might be necessary */
            R.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "img" &&
            R.target.getAttribute("src") !== "" /* avoid infinite loop */
        ) {
            R.target.setAttribute("src", "");
        };

        /* if the record specifies a sub-element mutation… */
        for (let N of R.addedNodes) {
            if (
                (N instanceof Element) && /* this check might be necessary */
                N.tagName.toLowerCase() === "img" &&
                N.getAttribute("src") !== "" /* avoid infinite loop */
            ) {
                N.setAttribute("src", "");
            };
        };
    };
})).observe(document, {
    /* changes wot we listen for */
    childList : true,
    subtree : true,
    attributes : true
});

/* part two: background-image styles */

let check_for_head_elem = function(_, Obs) {
    if (!document.head) {return;};
    Obs.disconnect();

    /* apply our style */
    let Style = document.createElement("style");
    document.head.appendChild(Style);
    Style.sheet.insertRule("* {background-image : none !important;}", 0);
};

let check_for_root_elem = function(_, Obs) {
    if (!document.documentElement) {return;};
    Obs.disconnect();

    /* observe until the <head> element is added */
    Obs = new MutationObserver(check_for_head_elem)
    Obs.observe(document.documentElement, {childList : true});
    check_for_head_elem(null, Obs); /* check here because it might exist already */
};

{/* observe until the <html> element is added */
    let Obs = new MutationObserver(check_for_root_elem);
    Obs.observe(document, {childList : true});
    check_for_root_elem(null, Obs); /* check here because it might exist already */
};
```

There are some other ways to get images on the page that I haven't taken into consideration (`<iframe>`, `<svg>`, `<canvas>`, `<li>` bullet points), but if necessary you should be able to use mutation observers or CSS to take care of those too.

Comment: I looked into MutationObserver but thought there may be a simpler way. I guess there isn't one in most cases, but Brock Adams' hint was what I needed in this case so I accepted that. Thanks for the information, in any case. :)